# new drop down list box entries are not showing in infopath form

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, forms-services

i have a custom info path form. I manually add a item to the drop down list box by editing the form in info path designer 2010 and published the form to the SharePoint server. But the newly added drop down list item is not showing when i try to add new document.

I am using client based forms. Do i miss something?

Answer (score 0):

The InfoPath client tends to cache the form definition, so even though you have published an update, users are still getting an older version.

You could try incrementing the version number in the form template, by opening it in InfoPath Designer, going to File and then Form Options, and then on the Versioning tab increasing the version number. Also, make sure that the "Update template" is set to update automatically.